# How to split a string into a two line label

Tags: ios, string

I have a string of two words with a sign in the middle of the type "&" or so "/" in the text of the label, how do I put the first string with sign in the first row and the second string in the second line?

This is the code

```
if(self.labelTitle.text.length> self.labelTitle.bounds.size.width){
     self.labelTitle.numberOfLines =2;

       if([self.labelTitle.text rangeOfString:@"&"].location != NSNotFound){
            NSArray * separateString = [self.labelTitle.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
            NSString * firstString =[separateString objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *secondString =[separateString objectAtIndex:1];
            self.labelTitle.text = firstString;
            self.labelTitle.text = secondString;

        }else if ([self.labelTitle.text rangeOfString:@"/"].location != NSNotFound){
            //.....
        }
  }
```

Where I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In the code example you override the `firstString` with the `secondString`.
What you want to do is add set the `text` property one time and add a `\n` between strings:

```
if(self.labelTitle.text.length> self.labelTitle.bounds.size.width){
     self.labelTitle.numberOfLines =2;

       if([self.labelTitle.text rangeOfString:@"&"].location != NSNotFound){
            NSArray * separateString = [self.labelTitle.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
            NSString * firstString =[separateString objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *secondString =[separateString objectAtIndex:1];
            self.labelTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", firstString, secondString];

        }else if ([self.labelTitle.text rangeOfString:@"/"].location != NSNotFound){
            //.....
        }
  }
```